# Matching "\n" in string

Tags: java, regex

This may have been asked before but I haven't come across an answer. I have a string that looks like

```
" ___________________ \n|_ | ___ _ _|\n| | | _|___|"
```

which I am passing to a java program as a command line argument. Literally just paste that string as a command line argument.

The first line in my program is

```
String [] array = args[0].split("\n");
```

I want to split it on the "\n" but I can't seem to do it with split("\n") or split("\\n"). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. We can't tell exactly what you've tried or what happened. We also don't know whether the string *literally* contains a backslash and an `n` or whether it's actually a line feed.

Comment: Please provide some code that you are used. \n is the perfect answer for line splitting

Comment: I'm passing that exact string as a command line argument. The first line of my program reads

String [] array = args[0].split("\n");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your string is passed in containing literal backslashes you have to match it using `split("\\\\n")`.

Explanation: to match a backslash in regex you have to excape it, so the regex is `\\n`. To input this through a java String-literal you have to excape each of the two backslashes in the regex, so it becomes `"\\\\n"`.

...just don't ask me about matching double backslashes ;-)

Answer (score 2):

try

```
String str =" ___________________ \n|_ | ___ _ _|\n| | | _|___|";
String[] arr = str.split("\n");
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
```

Comment: You are escaping newline

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
String lines[] = String.split("\\r?\\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\n   -  New Line Feed      
\r   -  Carriage Return    


String input = "___________________ \n|_ | ___ _ _|\n| | | _|___|";
String[] splitValue = input.split("[\\r\\n]+");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String data=" ___________________ \n|_ | ___ _ _|\n| | | _|___|";       
String data1[]=data.split("\\n");
System.out.println(data);
```

Gives output.

```
 ___________________ 
|_ | ___ _ _|
| | | _|___|
```